# editing design to be the best

Tags: css

between links but i can't here is the [**live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j2LrQ/55/). Here is the css class which i tried to make it later , please help me to know how to edit it and i need to know why this lines appears to me 
 between links but i can't here is the [**live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j2LrQ/5/). Here is the css class which i tried to make it later , please help me to know how to edit it and i need to know why this lines appears to me

```
body {
    font: 10px normal Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0;  
}
.container {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#113388;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul#topnav {
   margin: 0; padding: 0;

   list-style: none;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   background: #113388;
   position:relative;
   text-align:center;
}
ul#topnav li {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0; padding: 0;
   border-right: 1px solid #555;

}
ul#topnav li a {
   padding: 10px 15px;
   display: block;
   color: #f0f0f0;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-align:center;

}

ul#topnav li span {
    padding: 15px 0;
    position: absolute;
                left: 0; top: 100%;
                display: none;
                text-align:Center;
                width: 100%;
                background: #558ED5;
                color: #fff;
                -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
            }
ul#topnav li:hover span { display: block;}
ul#topnav li span a { display: inline;  }
ul#topnav li span a:hover {text-decoration: underline; }
```

Comment: Hey! I worked on your problem yesterday and then your question got marked as a duplicate because you essentially posted it twice in the same day :( .... I posted a solution to your problem so please review it and maybe vote on it since I think I fixed your problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to you css file :

```
li{border:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `border-right: 1px solid #555;` property: http://jsfiddle.net/j2LrQ/7/